# How to choose to have an element removed from a list in R?

Tags: r, subset

Say I have a list consisting of a range of integers from 1-10 with repetition and I want to remove all the 0s from that list, is there an easy way to go about doing that?

Something like na.omit but for my choice of elements?

Comment: Reproducible example?

Comment: `x[ x == 0 ] <- NA` then use na.omit. Or maybe `x[ x != 0 ]`.

Comment: @Laterow, I don't think it's a duplicate, since this question aims at subsetting a `list`

Comment: @zx8754 what is this process called (x[ x == 0 ] <- NA), the use of square brackets and double equals, ive never seen anything like that before.

Comment: @Qwertford This is a combination of subsetting (`[`) and assignment (`<-`). It say assign all elements in the *vector* x that are to 0 the value NA (missing). Note that in R terminology, x is a *vector*, not a list. See ` help("[")` and  help("<-") for more details.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

since you did not provide an example I create a list `ls`

```
ls <- list(rep(0:10, 10))

lsnew <- ls[[1]][ls[[1]] != 0]
```

It should be mentioned that `lsnew` is a numeric vector, not a list!

This is a simple example of *subsetting* in R. For further information on subsetting different data structures refer to:

- [R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Getting_a_subset_of_a_data_structure/)
- [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Comment: which package is this a part  of? I looked in help and couldn't find it.

Comment: This is base R. You don't need any packages for lists. Some details on subsetting [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Comment: Where can I learn to use those square brackets? Ive never seen them before and dont understand. what you've written.

Comment: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Getting_a_subset_of_a_data_structure/ or http://www.cookbook-r.com/Basics/Indexing_into_a_data_structure/

Answer (score 1):

extending @loki's answer you can also exclude more than one element

```
ls <- list(rep(0:10, 10))

#excluding 0
lsnew <- ls[[1]][which(ls[[1]] != 0)]

#excluding 0 & 1
lsnew <- ls[[1]][! ls[[1]] %in% c(0,1)]
```

Comment: I ment generalising to the exclusion of more than one element. I edited my answer to reflect that `which` is not needed.